# GA4 - "Pages and screens" report - fewer views than users?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

In the "Pages and screens" report of a site I'm looking, a bunch of pages have view counts much lower than users:

[image: Weird view/user count discrepancy in GA4]

Is there any  reasonable explanation for this, or might there be an actual issue with the GA4 installation?

Comment: Do you have any filters in place here? Specifically are you looking at a single page? GA4's filters tend to cause unclear results like this.

Comment: This is in the generic "Pages and screens" report (filters are only in 'Explore', right?), and it affects a bunch of pages.

Comment: You can apply filters to the standard reports. If you've filtered the report to only show certain pages/screens, then views being considerably lower than users would be probable, because GA4 is unintuitively showing all users for the site, but views only for the filtered pages/screens. The only other issue I could think of is that you're not properly logging screen/pageviews, but the number of events in your screenshot suggests that's not the case.

Comment: Yes, I guess that's why I wondered if there was an actual problem with the installation

Comment: What kind of site do you have? Is it a single page application? If so, you need to make sure your tagging is setup properly to register the URL fragments.

Comment: It's a regular site. I do think somehow the implementation of GA is the problem, but don't have enough access to investigate fully

Answer (score 0):

It might be thresholding.
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9383630?hl=en

Are you using Google signals?

People using Google signals for remarketing aresubject to thresholding.
Look for a little red triangle in your google analytics screen. This causes some data to be withheld to try to prevent you from identifying specific customers based on the data.

If it is thresholding. The way to fix it is to turn off google signals. (This turns off the collection of remarketing audiences.)

Comment: Thanks for your interest - no, I have a green tick, "Unsampled report. This report is based on 100% of available data."

Comment: Well, crud it isn't thresholding then.